# cast string of day-month-year to date in mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying to cast the string:

```
11-APR-14
```

To a date.  I have tried

```
str_to_date('11-APR-14','%d/%m/%Y') from table
```

But no such luck.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select str_to_date('11-APR-14','%d-%M-%Y')
```

**Output -** April, 11 2014 00:00:00

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35700)